# how to publish a facebook OG action with iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to post opengraph on users' wall/feed/ticker WITHOUT running my own server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996473/is-it-possible-to-post-opengraph-on-users-wall-feed-ticker-without-running-my-o)

I am trying to figure out the way to create some actions to my app and then, post them as actions in my users timeline/feed/ticker through my app for the related actions.
Reading through facebook's dev site, I understand that the flow is simple for a `facebook application that requires my own server` like this:

1. `get authorized`   (i.e. `log in`+`allow access`)
2. once logged in, post using `curl -F` (namely POST method)

But this is done for likes and comments depends on the URL you used right?
if it was `graph.facebook.com/ID/comments` or `graph.facebook.com/ID/likes` with a token of course being sent through POST.

But how to do this with iOS ? It doesn't have it's curl (not normally) I assume it's done through the SDK somehow to emulate cURL ?

Answer (score 0):

A good method for this is [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:graphObject:completionHandler].

The BooleanOGSample in Facebook SDK for iOS demonstrates this.

In that sample, there is an example of this in BOGFirstViewController.m in the method postAction:leftOperand:rightOperand:result:tryReauthIfNeeded.  This method assumes the user is already logged in.  It then asks for "publish_actions" permission if it does not already have that permission.  Finally, it creates a BOGGraphBooleanAction, populates it, posts it, and then updates the UI based on the result of the post.

In the same file, the method ogObjectForTruthValue has examples of Open Graph objects used in the post.  You can open the URLs in that method to see how the metadata would look in your html for objects your users will act on.