# Is it possible to post opengraph on users' wall/feed/ticker WITHOUT running my own server?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am new to facebook development and I am still trying to figure out how things work for facebook development.
So my app, which is designed for iOS, wants to post an `action post` on my users' facebook page/feed/ticker.
I want the app to post various `action` types for all kinds of possible actions my app can do.
I want to understand. If the app simply posts to facebook, and facebook has all the definitions I made to my facebook-app, meaning it knows where to link the ACTION, it knows where to link the OBJECT. The extra stuff need for facebook will be supplied when my users posts by the app on the users device....
Why do I need to run a server ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the Open Graph Protocol is defined (ogp.me). Objects exist as web pages for users to have richer web experiences. A non-mobile user must have a way to interact with your object when he sees the action on his ticker.

> The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph. For instance, this is used on Facebook to allow any web page to have the same functionality as any other object on Facebook
>
> To turn your web pages into graph objects, you need to add basic metadata to your page. We've based the initial version of the protocol on RDFa which means that you'll place additional  tags in the  of your web page.