# Can I post openGraph actions within my iOS app without a server?

Tags: ios, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to post opengraph on users' wall/feed/ticker WITHOUT running my own server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996473/is-it-possible-to-post-opengraph-on-users-wall-feed-ticker-without-running-my-o)

I'd like my iOS app to post actions on users timeline/feed/wall. For example if a user rated an article I'd like the iOS app to post:
"Ken just *`rated`* an *`article`* on *`myApp!`*" with additional icons and text.
Does this type of post require me to own a server? Or is it possible to simply post such a thing from the iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access token, and your iOs app registered at developers.facebook.com you can do some actions without a server. But for things like "Ken just rated an article" you need a server because facebook makes a request to your server to get a list of actions (in your case you would have to define the action "rate" and then the object "article" and then define that user can rate articles). 
But thats only how it works in facebook canvas and Websites, may be different in iOs Apps..